# React RTK http middleware

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rtk-query

I want to add a middleware to all API calls with React RTK.
To be specific I want to add the Firebase Performance Monitoring plugin to monitor the HTTP request: https://rnfirebase.io/perf/usage#http-request-tracing.

So how can I add a middleware just for the API calls?

This is our api (this is off course not the whole api but you get the poin):

```
export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: Config.API_ENDPOINT,
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      const token = (getState() as RootState).app.token 

      if (token) {
        headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
      }

      return headers
    }
  }),
  tagTypes: ['AuthToken'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    auth: builder.query<BaseResponse<AuthResult>, any>({
      query: () => ({
        url: '/auth/token',
        method: 'POST',
        responseHandler: (response) => response.json()
      }),
      providesTags: ['AuthToken'],
    }),
   }),
  }),
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To add a middleware specifically for API calls in React RTK, you can utilize the ***baseQuery*** option provided by ***createApi*** and customize it with your desired middleware.

In your code, you are using ***fetchBaseQuery*** as the base query for making API calls. To add the Firebase Performance Monitoring plugin as middleware, you can create a custom ***fetchBaseQuery*** function that wraps the original ***fetchBaseQuery*** and applies the monitoring plugin.

Add the following snippet to your code:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getPerformance, trace } from 'firebase/performance'

// Initialize Firebase Performance Monitoring
const firebaseConfig = { /* Your Firebase config */ }
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const perf = getPerformance(app)

// Custom fetchBaseQuery with middleware
const customFetchBaseQuery = ({ baseUrl, prepareHeaders }) => {
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl,
    prepareHeaders,
})
return async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
const { url } = args
const traceName = `HTTP ${args.method} ${url}`

// Start Firebase Performance Monitoring trace
const perfTrace = trace(perf, traceName)
perfTrace.start()

try {
  // Call the original fetchBaseQuery
  const result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
  
  // Stop the trace on success
  perfTrace.stop()

  return result
} catch (error) {
  // Stop the trace on error
  perfTrace.stop()

  throw error
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I do this with TS types? Is it possible for customFetchBaseQuery to inherit fetchBaseQuery types?

Comment: And how do I get the status code and response headers from `const response = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)`?